# Access VBA to Run Macro with Dates Loop

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I have a macro called "ForecastMacro" in an Access Database that needs a date selected to run. I would like to run for all of 2017. In Access I have created a form that holds dates [FormDates]. The specified form date [FDate] is then used in the macro's queries to create a prediction model. There is criteria in multiple queries inside  the macro "ForecastMacro" where date = [FormDates]![FDate]

1. I'm not sure how to run a macro using vba code in access
2. and also move to the next date in the dates form [FormDates]

I found this code but i'm not sure how to implement it in such a way that will iterate the [FormDates] and then run the "ForecastingMacro"?

```
Publice Sub LoopOverDateRange()
Const startdate As Date = #1/1/2017#
Const enddate As Date = #12/31/17#
Dim d As Date
Dim i As Integer 
i = 1
For d = startdate To enddate
d
i=i++
Next
End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!!!! :)

Comment: Eh... What exactly are you asking? I'm not sure what you mean by _I'm not sure how to run a macro using vba code in access_. Are you just looking for `DoCmd.RunMacro`? Also, that code doesn't look valid. VBA doesn't do `++`

Comment: Im not great at VBA in Access so i believe DoCmd.RunMacro is what i want. Do I just throw that into the VBA thing? Or there a header that needs to go in? so it is DoCmd.RunMacro "ForecastingMacro" then how do i iterate the form with dates?

Comment: Well, as said, your VBA doesn't look valid, but I'm unclear on exactly what you want. You can just use `DoCmd.RunMacro "MyMacro"` to run a macro called _MyMacro_ in VBA. But that code won't compile, so it won't work. There are multiple lines that are unclear to me, like what is `i` doing there, besides causing a compile error? Why is one line just `d` and nothing else? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: ok ignore the whole code seen there, I don't know what i'm doing and that was an attempt. Apparently a very bad attempt. What I am trying to do is... I have a form and this form selects a date to be used in a macro. I need to run the macro (starting date 1/1/16 on the form)  then change to the next date (1/2/16) in the form then run the macro again, and repeat until i hit 11/7/17. Then stop. I have been doing this manually and would like to do it in VBA but i'm a novice.

Answer (score 0):

The method incrementing i is definitely not VBA.

Access macros cannot call Subs, only Functions.

VBA can call a macro with `DoCmd.RunMacro "macro name"`. However, this method cannot pass data via arguments.

VBA procedure can have arguments to pass in data for manipulation. Make procedure a Function so macro can call it.

```
Public Function LoopOverDateRange(dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date)
Dim d As Date
d = dteSart
Do While d < dteEnd
    d = d + 1
    Debug.Print d 'or do something else with d
Next
End Function
```

Call Function from macro with RunCode method: `LoopOverDateRange(input, input)`
The inputs can be references to textboxes on form or TempVars.

Better, don't use macros - just VBA.